# Adding attachments to workitems from silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

For a project we need to add attachments to workitems through a Silverlight application.
Our Silverlight app has a WCF service with which it communicates to our TFS 2010 server with the TFS API.

I can bind attachments from within the WCF service just fine, however what are the best practices to do this through Silverlight, seeing that SL is clientside and the WCF service serverside?

The way I look at it is that I need to upload the attachment to the server first, add the workitemid and the serverpath of the newly uploaded file, in some sort of log. Run a process/application on the server which searches the log for new entries, and then call the webservice which will add the attachment to the workitem.

Is this the best way to go?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kroonwijk, for your suggestions on how to make the approach somewhat simpeler.

In the end I processed the file(s) to a byte[] on the Silverlight client side.
This byte[] is sent to the webservice accompanied by a workitemID. On the Server side(webservice) the byte[] gets saved to a temporary file on the server, and gets attached and saved to the workitem.

All works well with one WCF call, without having to use a process or file transfers to the server.

**Point of notice:** you might have to increase the message quota limit in your WCF bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally approach this as you described, without creating the intermediate logfile:

1. Upload the attachment using your SL client to the server.
2. Calculate the serverpath of the attachment.
3. Call the WCF service to process the attachment and specify the serverpath and workitem id.